# What is the best way to handle paginated API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to consume an API which returns structure below.

```
{
  data: [{...},{...},{...},{...},...],
  nextUrl: "url_goes_here";
}
```

The pages end when the nextUrl is null. I want to collect all the elements in data into one array while going through the paginated responses. I tried the following code segment.

```js
const getUserData = async (url) => {
    const result = await fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        dataList= [...dataList, ...res.data];
        console.log(res.data)
        if (res.nextUrl !== null) {
          getUserData(res.nextUrl);
        } else {
          console.log("else ", dataList);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {});
  return result;
}
```

The console.log can print the result. but I want to get all the data to get into a variable that can be used for further processing later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach using recursion isn't bad at all, but you're not *returning* the chunk of data (there's no value returned by your second `.then` handler). (You're also falling into the `fetch` pitfall of not checking `ok`. It's a flaw IMHO in the `fetch` API design.)

There's no need for recursion though. I'd be tempted to just use a loop:

```
const getUserData = async (url) => {
    const result = [];
    while (url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        const {data, nextUrl} = await response.json();
        result.push(...data);
        url = nextUrl;
    }
    return result;
};
```

But if you want to use recursion:

```
const getUserData = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    const {data, nextUrl} = await response.json();
    if (nextUrl) {
        data.push(...await getUserData(nextUrl));
    }
    return data;
};
```

or

```
const getUserData = async (url, result = null) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    const {data, nextUrl} = await response.json();
    if (!result) {
        result = data;
    } else {
        result.push(...data);
    }
    if (nextUrl) {
        result = await getUserData(nextUrl, result);
    }
    return result;
};
```