# Loop over next_url in API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, do-while

I'm using Node on AWS Lambda to call an API which gives X results, if more exist, it provides a "next_url" URI to call for the next set of results.

How do I continuously loop, passing the URI to the next iteration of the loop, if next_url is present and terminate if "next_url" is no longer provided?

Comment: Can you provide your current implementation?

Comment: Solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364234/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-paginated-api-in-javascript